# Converting m/s to body lengths / s

Tags: ecology, ichthyology

I am trying to calculate speed of fish in body lengths / s. As of now, I have speeds for each of my individuals in m/s. To convert each individual fish's speed in body lengths / s (bl/s; using each fish's body length), from m/s, I assume I can simply divide each m/s value by the body length of the fish.

For example:

I have a speed of 0.35 m/s, Fish A's length is 0.66 m. To convert into bl/s I should divide 0.35 / 0.66 to get 0.53 bl/s.

Is this correct or is there some kind of unit conversions that come into this? Since it's relative to the fish's length, I assume this is ok? If this isn't correct, would you please show me the correct way to calculate this?

Comment: For all unit conversions, you want to learn to multiply by ratios that are equal to 1 and make things cancel. So if you have units of "x/s" and you want to express in "y/s", you need to multiply by "y/x" so that the xs cancel. To make it work, you need y/x to be equal to 1. For example, if x = 1 meter then you could use y = 100 centimeters. If you want y = 1 body length then you need x = ____ meters, whatever makes it equal to y. Whatever units you choose, when you do this you're always multiplying by 1 overall which we know doesn't change the actual number.

Comment: Thank you for the response.... so if I have 0.35 m/s and want body length (which is expressed in m) / s, I need to multiply by y/x which would be 1 body length/0.66 m... when you cross multiply this gives you 0.231 bl/s? Is this correct? What did I do wrong initially? I thought that since body length is just a ratio of 1 m, I would just need to divide to see that ratio through.

Comment: No no, no "cross multiplying". You did it correctly the first time:$$\pu{0.35 \frac{m}{s}}=\pu{0.35 \frac{m}{s}}\times \underbrace{ \frac{\pu{1 bl}}{\pu{0.66 m}}}_1=\pu{0.53 \frac{m}{s}}$$

Comment: @Domen did you mean 0.53 bl/s? (even though in this case bl is measured in m)

Comment: Arghh, yes, of course, my mistake :)

Comment: Thank you so much!